# Generating the toggle matrix for a "Lights out" variant

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

In the traditioal 3x3 lights-out game, the toggle matrix for the topmost left field looks like:

```
1 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0
```

This means, that when we press the first button, only its own and the lights next to it are toggled. In my variant the toggle matrix for one button looks like

```
1 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

Every light in the same row and column are toggled. To efficiently solve this, a n^2 x n^2 matrix is generated, the toggle matrix for a button is converted to a vector with [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and appended to that matrix:

```
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 <-- this is the example matrix
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
```

for my variant it would look like

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

In [this lecture](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~jtmulhol/math302/notes/24-Lights-Out.pdf) (p. 6), they generate the matrix similiar to this (adapted to pure python):

```
def GenerateToggleMatrix(n):
    result = []

    for i in range(n*n):
        row = [0]*n*n
        result.append(row)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):

            col = n*i+j            #row-major
            result[col][col] = 1

            if i > 0:   result[col][col-n] = 1
            if i < n-1: result[col][col+n] = 1
            if j > 0:   result[col][col-1] = 1
            if j < n-1: result[col][col+1] = 1
    return result
```

I have a complete brain-freeze adapting this to my variant, can someone help me?

Comment: Just a small comment because I almost got tripped up because of this: in your variant matrix, you have a typo. Position (6, 9) should be 1 and not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a loop to change all elements in the same row or column.

i.e. change:

```
        if i > 0:   result[col][col-n] = 1
        if i < n-1: result[col][col+n] = 1
        if j > 0:   result[col][col-1] = 1
        if j < n-1: result[col][col+1] = 1
```

to

```
        for k in range(n):
            result[col][n*i+k] = 1
            result[col][n*k+j] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is almost embarrassing :D